# How isolate between two times in pandas data frame and then modify just those values in a larger pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I have a large pandas dataframe. I want to select a subset (time range) of the dataframe and modify it by multiplying it by -1. I was trying something like this but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

```
g[g.between_time('22:55:00', '22:59:35')] =  g[g.between_time('22:55:00', '22:59:35')] * -1
```

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work ? Can you provide the specific error, as well as an example of your data, like the result of `print(g.head())`? Remember to format your code and data with backticks to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
g.update(g[g.between_time('22:55:00', '22:59:35')] * -1)
```